# How does Bloomberg Barclays US Aggregate Bond compare to ICE US Treasury Core Bond?

Tags: bonds, government-bonds, bond-etf

I'm looking at two US aggregate bonds trying to understand why one is more popular than the other.

1. [iShares US Aggregate Bond UCITS ETF - 0.25% TER - Bloomberg Barclays](https://www.justetf.com/de-en/etf-profile.html?isin=IE00B44CGS96)
2. [iShares US Treasury Bond UCITS ETF - 0.07% TER - ICE US Treasury Core](https://www.justetf.com/de-en/etf-profile.html?isin=IE00BK95B138)

It seems Bloomberg Barclays ETF is more popular than ICE ETF although it has higher expense ratio. I found [this](https://www.theice.com/publicdocs/data/ice-treasury-methodology.pdf) that describes ICE allocation formulas but I can't fully comprehend it. Is there anything inherently wrong with ICE Treasury Core index? How does it compare to Bloomberg Barclays index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have different constituents. The ICE US Treasury fund consists of only US Treasuries:

> The ICE US Treasury Core Bond index tracks US Treasuries. Time to maturity: At least one year

while the Bloomberg fund consists of treasuries, other gov bonds, and corporate bonds:

> The Bloomberg Barclays US Aggregate Bond index tracks USD denominated fixed rate bonds including Treasuries, government-related, securitised and corporate securities. Rating: Investment Grade.

You should expect higher return *on average* from the Bloomberg fund, but also higher risk (in terms of fluctuations) because of the credit risk of corporate bonds and securitized products (e.g. Mortgage-Backed Securities).

BTW do not go by the fund price to gauge whether a fund is "expensive" or "popular" or not - fund price is largely irrelevant since you can buy fractional units (you can buy 100 EURO of either funds just as easily). What matters is the expected *return* and the *expense ratio*.